# Google web authorization broker and electron desktop app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-api, electron, google-oauth

Background:

My project consists of a Vue 2 Front end encased in an electron shell with an asp.net core web API backend.

What I am trying to do is get a google authorization token and refresh token so that I can create a folder and files within that folder on a users google drive. I also want to display a list of the folders content in my front end.

I have tried using the new Google Identity Services code in my front end but when launching my app and clicking on the google button I the following error

```
Error 400: invalid_request

If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google policies:

redirect_uri: storagerelay://file/?id=auth12850
```

I think this is because electron is seen more of a desktop app which according to the google documentation needs to use a loopback address to open the system browser and authenticate from there.

So I tried the google authentication api on my backend which is C# I have the google web authorization broker setup and when I run my backend and call my endpoint I get the google sign in page and can get the authorization token and refresh token.

Question:
Is there a way to capture the URL of the page that comes up for authentication so that I can put it in a child window in electron.

or a way to pass the data to the front end so that I can show the list of files to my users.

Would I still need to use a loopback address even though I am getting the authentication page from the web broker?

If I do need the loopback functionality would I be better off using the data from the Google Desktop Application example rather than the google Web broker?

To learn more about electron you can go [Electron website](https://www.electronjs.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the nodejs google api to get this working  this is my code that now returns an auth token and refresh token.

This code opens a child window when the authorize button is clicked and loads the google login/account select. Once authorized it shows the app permission window. When a user clicks allow the url is invoked in the loopback of the created server and the auth file is created in the specified directory.

part one successful.. now on to getting everything else working.

```
/* Google authentication */
function createGoogleWindow() {

    const http = require('http');
    const path = require('path');
    const service = google.drive('v3');
    const TOKEN_DIR = path.join(process.env.APPDATA, 'home-inventory', 'bin');
    const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(TOKEN_DIR, 'home-inventory.json');
    const querystring = require('querystring');

    let googleWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        parent: win,
        height: 600,
        width: 400,
        webPreferences: {
            webSecurity: false,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        }
    });
    if (isDevelopment) googleWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    googleWindow.menuBarVisible = false;
    googleWindow.on('closed', () => {
        googleWindow = null;
    });

    const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        CLIENT_ID,
        CLIENT_SECRET,
        REDIRECT_URI
    );
    // check if we previously stored a token
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function (err, token){
        if (err) {
            getNewToken(oauth2Client);
        } else {
            oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        }
    });
    
    const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES
    });

    function callback (auth) {
        service.files.list({
            auth: auth,
            q: `name contains '.bak'`,
            pageSize: 50,
            fields: "nextPageToken, files(id,name,size,parents,createdTime)",
        }, function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('The API returned an error: ', err);
                return;
            }
            const files = response.files;
            if (files.length === 0) {
                console.warn('no files found');
            } else {
                console.warn('files', files, auth.credentials.access_token);
            }
        });
    }

    function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
        function storeToken(token) {
            try {
                fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
            } catch (err) {
                if (err.code !== 'EEXIST') {
                    throw err
                }
            }
            fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                // console.debug('file was saved successfully');
                googleWindow.close();
            });
            // console.warn('Token stored to: ', TOKEN_PATH);
        }

        function handler(request, response, server, callback) {
            let qs = querystring.parse(require('url').parse(request.url).query);
            oauth2Client.getToken(qs.code, function (err, tokens) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Error getting oAuth tokens: ', err);
                }
                oauth2Client.credentials = tokens;
                storeToken(tokens);
                callback(oauth2Client)
                server.close();
            });
        }

        const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
            handler(request, response, server, callback);
        }).listen(8181, function() {
            googleWindow.loadURL(url);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a web app I think your going to have an issue

> Users will be redirected to this path after they have authenticated with Google. The path will be appended with the authorization code for access, and must have a protocol. It can’t contain URL fragments, relative paths, or wildcards, and can’t be a public IP address.

Not just because of the format but because its going to need to be a domain you can register.

If you go with an installed app then the redirect uri is https://127.0.0.1

Im not sure how you are going to get this to route back properly.

Comment: This would be considered as a installed app. So the loopback is the way to go Figuring out how to do that is my problem. I have analyzed the six year old desktop example may provide the best insight on how to get it done. I think. my question to that is the example format still viable meaning am I going to have to change it in a years time to something else .

Comment: I should have updated examples on my website for drive https://www.daimto.com

Comment: I got some of the code working with a loopback I can get the auth tokens now i just need to save them to a file that can be accessed then try to get the drive stuff going using the REST endpoints.

Comment: If you get it working please anwser your question i would love to see it.

Comment: I posted an answer to my question.. one other thing I was wondering about. How long does an installed app token last before I have to refresh it?. And should I refresh it every time my app is opened ?

Comment: access tokens expire after an hour

Comment: Even for a desktop app? the TTL number in the file is way bigger than an hour .?

Comment: 3600 in seconds is 60 minutes.   It's standard with oauth2.   Dosent matter what type of application.   Just use the refresh token to get a new access tokens.